# Why can't I run a while loop after an if/else statement in a function in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to code the Collatz Sequence but for some reason, my while loop is just being completely skipped after the if/else statement in a FUNCTION. Does an else statement skip all other code after it's in a function? I've tried putting the while loop before the if/else and even tried to include the while loop inside the if/else. I'm new to programming.

```
def collatz():
   number = input()
   if int(number) % 2 == 0 :
      print(int(number) // 2)
   else:
      print( 3 * int(number) + 1 )
   while number != 1 :
      collatz()

collatz()
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string value, therefore `number` is a string which will never equal the integer 1.  So the `while number != 1` statement is always true.

Comment: @JohnGordon Would you mind add that as an answer instead of as a comment?

Comment: @OscarRyz This is a simple error and didn't seem worthy of a formal answer.  Especially since the question title has nothing to do with the real problem.

Comment: You write `while number != 1` collatz(), which calls your program recursively.  At this point, you're back at the top of the program, waiting for the user to type another input.  You need `number = int(number)` and then `while number != 1` at the top of your code, with the next four lines being the body of the while loop.

Comment: can you fix your indentation/formatting? it's unclear what your code is doing, since the code after `def` must be indented. the syntax and scope is super important in your question, so this may be causing some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You call to `input()` returns a string value, therefore the variable `number` is a string which will never equal the integer `1`.

So the `while number != 1` statement is always true and `collatz()` is called again.

You can add the conversion when you read the input and then it will work as you intent (you might need to catch an error if the input cannot be transformed)

```
def collatz():
    number = int(input())
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
    else:
        print(3 * number + 1)
    while number != 1 :
        collatz()

collatz()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this i guess. You don't need to write it in a recursive way. Because every time you call your function you will accept a new input so your calculation will never end.

```
def collatz():
    number = int(input())
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = int(number/2)
            print(number)
        else:
            number = int(number*3 + 1)
            print(number)

collatz()
```

I always cast to `int` cause when you divide your number to 2 even it is an even number you will get float.
Here is the output for the number 5:

```
5
16
8
4
2
1
```